# How to change the program path in Ghidra

Tags: ghidra

I have a Ghidra project with an imported binary file, which was created on computer A, then I want to move this project to Computer B. However, the path of the binary file isn't the same as A. How do I change the path setting in Ghidra?

Edited:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF7aB.png) (Black blocks are the original path in computer A.)

Comment: How are you moving the project? Ghidra will refuse a project that was not created on the same machine, you have to either use `File > Archive Current Project` or a Ghidra Server to sync between computers. Also what kind of path setting do you mean? Once the binary is imported the paths on the computer should not matter anymore anymore

Comment: I just copied the project folder to computer B. The reason I want to change the path setting is because I built a new debugger included Ghidra from source, and GDB debugger needs original binary file to run debug processes. So it turns out this question.

Comment: Interesting, Ghidra used to reject copied folders like this, but maybe that changed. The debugger integration is fairly new and still experimental, but I can check where this binary file path is stored and how to change it, I actually need that information for some other things and wasn't aware that Ghidra stores this.

Comment: Is there some concrete error or stacktrace you get when this fails? That would make it a lot easier for me to find the relevant part of the codebase

Comment: Yes, I've updated the error message in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Ghidra uses the information from `currentProgram.getExecutablePath()` which takes the value from the options stored with the binary information inside the project:

Code snippet from `ghidra.program.database.ProgramDB#getExecutablePath`:

```java
    @Override
    public String getExecutablePath() {
        String path = null;
        Options pl = getOptions(PROGRAM_INFO);
        path = pl.getString(EXECUTABLE_PATH, UNKNOWN);
        return path == null ? UNKNOWN : path;
    }

    @Override
    public void setExecutablePath(String path) {
        Options pl = getOptions(PROGRAM_INFO);
        pl.setString(EXECUTABLE_PATH, path);
        changed = true;
    }
```

To change this you should be able to simply use the corresponding `setExecutablePath` method, e.g. by running

```py
currentProgram.setExecutablePath("/new/path/to/binary.elf")
```

inside the Python REPL.