# How to change the FSRL for a file in Ghidra

Tags: java, jython, ghidra

Is there a similar way to change the FSLR ("File System Resource Locator") of a file in GHidra, like there is to change its "Executable Location" with 'currentProgram.setExecutablePath("/new/path/to/binary.elf")' as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65733481/how-to-change-the-program-path-in-ghidra)?

There doesn't seem to be a GUI option and entering the currentProgram.setFSRL("/new/path/to/binary.elf") into the Python REPL only results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ghidra.program.database.ProgramDB' object has no attribute 'setFSRL'
```

While manually editing the ".db" files in the "idata" directory with a hex-editor and then re-saving the file in Ghidra does seem to work, that might break things in unexpected ways, so that's probably not a good work-around either.